# How do I install the GDAL bindings for C#/.NET 4.5.1?

Tags: gdal, c#, osgeo

I'm trying to use the C# gdal bindings but I get an error in my C# code which says "Unable to load DLL 'gdal_wrap': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)".

I've had a look at the dependencies for gdal_csharp.dll and everything looks okay. Two things that stood out though were that the csharp dll is a 32 bit dll, while all the dependencies are for a 64 bit system (my machine has a 64 bit CPU). Also, the file ieshims.dll was listed as a dependency, but from what I gather, it isn't strictly necessary that it be installed.

I've tried installing the files manually via a zip file and also using the .msi installer for the gdal core libraries. I made sure to add the paths to the gdal executables to my system path.

I downloaded the binaries from here:
http://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1800-x64-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1.zip

And I roughly followed this guide for installation instructions:
http://vipassanaandenvironmentalinformatics.blogspot.co.nz/2013/03/getting-started-with-c-and-gdal.html

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, for which the binaries are available on the site above.

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14353502/2258

Comment: Thanks for posting that question, I put the gdal_wrap.dll into dependency walker and it turns out that there is a missing dependency called gdal111.dll, I'll try to track this down and post an update on my progress.

Comment: @AndreLashley I am getting the same issue with unable to load gdal_wrap. Any suggestions?

Comment: @StealthRabbi I ended up using the gdal command line tools via OSGEO4W and C# code. It was much easier to set up this way. But of course you don't get all the benefits of using the C# gdal libraries.

Comment: Did you use this to create GEOTiffs? How easy is it to distribute just the items needed to create GEOTiffs with your C# application?

Comment: We  used the library to create tiled jpeg files from geoTiffs, with the gdal tools, they were installed separately on the machine (using the OSGEO4W) software package and then called from C# via a process to which we passed any arguments it needed to generate the tiles (file paths, output flags etc.). It wasn't very difficult at all.

Comment: Don't know if you ever solved this, but this turned up for me trying to solve the same issue, and I ended up adding an answer to the SO question link in comment number one which solved the issue.  If it helps I'll happily post it as a question on this question too.  SO-GIS seems a more appropriate place anyway.

Comment: I got past it eventually but I think I ended up referencing a different install path in my .NET project. There was a faulty installation attempt that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get the package from NuGet and then you need to call static method`GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal()` from `GdalConfiguration.cs/vb` at startup to set process environmental variables. Call `GdalConfiguration.ConfigureOgr()` if you want to use OGR as well.