# GDalConfigure.cs is missing when I install GDal Core with NuGet in C# Visual Studio

Tags: gdal, c#, visual-studio

According to this post:
[How to Install GDal Bindings for C#](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138184/how-do-i-install-the-gdal-bindings-for-c-net-4-5-1)
It says all I have to do to get GDal working is install with NuGet package, and then call ConfigureGdal(). So I did the basic steps, and it fails. Here is what I did:

> I create new .net CORE 2.0 solution.
>
> I go to Project -> Manage NuGet Packages.
>
> I install GDal Core 1.0.

I look at the Solution Explorer and find that GDalConfigure.cs did not get automatically created.

As such, if I try to call GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal(), I get an error because it doesn't exist.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can call Gdal.AllRegister() instead of GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal()